# Missing Data when reading/buffering WebResponse Stream

Tags: c#, .net, xml, webrequest

I am working on a .Net application that's supposed to download and process large XML files. It takes a while to download those XML therefore we need to be able to cancel it. Here's my code responsible for "cancelable" download:

```
                bool canceled = false;
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    int Lenght = 2048;
                    Byte[] buffer = new byte[Lenght];
                    List<Byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

                    int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Lenght);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        bytes.AddRange(buffer);
                        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Lenght);
                        // BackgroundWorker instance
                        if (!worker.CancellationPending) continue; // break if cancelation is pending

                        canceled = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (canceled) break;
                    xmlAsString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```

However for some reason the last buffered package (2048 bytes in this case)  gets "lost somewhere" and I get exceptions afterwards when I try to parse **xmlAsString**.

> Here's an example of expected XML

```
<experiments>
 <experiment>
  <Lots of  XML tags/>
  <organism>Homo sapiens</organism>
 </experiment>
</experiments>
```

> And xmlAsString after download looks something like this

```
<experiments>
 <experiment>
  <Lots of  XML tags/>
 <organism>Homo sap
```

However if i read stream byte by byte like this

> responseStream.ReadByte();

it works fine, but download speed slows down conciderably. Any guidence to whats could be causing this would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of using buffering like this when everything will be stored in a string anyway? [StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L426) works in the same way *without* slowing down. Your code constanly reallocates a list while `StreamReader` uses a single buffer to read data and write it to a `StringBuilder` with the necessary capacity.

Comment: Good point about using the `StreamReader`. However if I use `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` I can't cancel mid download correct? Also just tried using `StreamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)` in a same manner as above. Still get the same error - last part of downloaded XML missing.